# how adjust color levels in StreamDensity Plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

[image]I have a source in my flow so the whole streamplot comes out monotone. Whereas I would like something like a different colour for every .1 of the flowspeed from .5 to 1.2 (times the unit freestream speed) and not all the colours presumably lost right in the minute zone around the source singularity.  Tried ColorFunctionScaling True and false. Best can get is just with StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow" as in picture. Michael E2 kindly reverse engineered a similiar function to experiment with

```
   StreamDensityPlot[{{2,    y (y - 0.9)/20 + 1/(1 + 200 (y - 1)^2 + 80 
     x^2)}}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/3, StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Comment: Could you please load enough Mathematica code so that this problem can be replicated and studied by potential respondents?

Comment: I would say the range of the velocity is very narrow, at least away from $(0,1)$. Try `PlotLegends -> Automatic` to see what the velocity is. -- This gives a similar sort of plot, but I would say that the plot is accurate: `StreamDensityPlot[{2, 
  y (y - 0.9)/20 + 1/(1 + 200 (y - 1)^2 + 80 x^2)}, {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0,
   2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 400]`

Comment: Ok very nice simulation of my function. I ran without the legends and got a very similiar picture

Comment: Ok doing a bit better with just plotting the perturbation to uniform flow as per Michael's comment but low colour levels still not enough